# How to call a specific method in RestFul API?

Tags: php

I have created this code:

```
header("Content-Type: application/json");

$method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
$request = explode("/", substr(@$_SERVER['PATH_INFO'], 1));

switch ($method) 
{
  case 'PUT':
    break;
  case 'POST':
    do_something_with_post($request);  
    break;
  case 'GET':
    do_something_with_get($request);  
    break;
  case 'DELETE':
    do_something_with_delete($request);  
    break;
  default:
    handle_error($request);  
    break;
}
```

Now suppose that I execute this command:

```
curl -X GET http://localhost/api/method/1
```

so in the `switch` is fired the `GET` case, how I can call the function `method` and pass the parameter `1`? 
how I should configure the code on the switch? Someone could help me to figure out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to parse the URI:

```
$pieces = explode('?', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$endpoint = $pieces[0];
$endpoint_parts = explode('/', $endpoint);
$api_method = $endpoint_parts[2];
$param = $endpoint_parts[3];
```

Then you can invoke `method` from your URL with 1 like this:

```
$api_method($param);
```

Comment: Okay, now is a bit clear. But I have few question: `1`. How can I call the exact method from `$api_method($param);` that is only a variable? - `2`. Where I should find all the methods? I mean the organization for methods `GET - POST - PUT - DELETE`. I'm going to create classes for each category. In my example I mentioned `method` as a function, but imagine that I've an application that manages users, so I would have an API file that manages the user, other components that handle user. How can I access these files and invoke the appropriate methods simply recognizing them in the switch?

Comment: 1 - read up on [variable functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php)

Comment: For the point two, I mean, essentially: where should I place all methods of the API for each content, like the `class User`, `class Foo`, `class Example`, etc...?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simplified way to route request paths to classes. This example assumes your base path is `/app` and you have a sub-folder called `/classes`. The class name and file name must match for this to work.

Example request:

`curl -X POST http://localhost/api/user/123`

Example route:

```
File....: /app/classes/api/User.php
Class...: new User()
Action..: postAction( $arg1 = 123 )
```

...

```
// default route
$base  = rtrim( str_replace( '\\', '/', __DIR__.'/app' ), '/' );
$area  = 'api';   // area (/api, /test, etc.)
$class = 'home';  // class name (Home.php -> new Home(), etc.)

// parse request
$verb  = strtolower( @$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] );
$path  = parse_url( @$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH );
$args  = explode( '/', trim( $path, '/' ) );

// extract area/class from request path
if( count( $args ) )
{
    $area = array_shift( $args );
}
if( count( $args ) )
{
    $class = array_shift( $args );
}

// finalize class name and file path 
$class  = str_replace( ' ', '', ucwords( str_replace( '-', ' ', $class ) ) );
$file   = $base .'/classes/'. $area .'/'. $class.'.php';
$output = null;

// load/execute class
if( is_file( $file ) )
{
    include_once( $file );

    if( class_exists( $class ) )
    {
        $callable = [ new $class(), $verb.'Action' ];

        if( is_callable( $callable ) )
        {
            $output = call_user_func_array( $callable, $args );
        }
    }
}

// send response output...
if( is_null( $output ) === false )
{
    // ...
}
else
{
    // handle error 
}
exit;
```